# Why "fiestas de árboles" and not "árboles de fiestas"?

Tags: traducción, gramática, preposiciones, adjetivos

I encountered the expression "fiestas de árboles"  in a [song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RuhWU6DrODk) by a Chilean singer whose lyrics are:

> Tus ojos son fiestas de árboles, son mi ventana.
>   Son estrellas que guían mi caravana.

Google translates the expression as "holiday tree" and my search shows it is about trees used in ceremonies. Now, shouldn't it be "árboles de fiestas", that is "trees of holiday"? "Fiestas de árboles" sounds like holidays fulls of trees, if that makes sense.

Comment: I think it's just poetic license so it's not an expression but a phrase made up by the writer

Answer (score 3):

First of all, these phrases sound very strange to me (I should have the context they are used into, in order to have a better understanding of them).

In Spanish such phrases may be an example of that is knoun as "Complemento del Nombre". I'm not sure if such a concept exists in English grammar. In Spanish you must think of that complement as some sort of adjective that specifies the role of the main noun.

Its structure is:

> [Main Noun] de [Specifier Noun]

So, with the phrase "***Fiestas de árboles***", you have:

1. *Fiestas* is the main noun.
2. *árboles* is the specifier.

then you may have these meanings (among others, depending on the context):

- Parties attended by trees (should be better expressed with: *Fiestas de los árboles*).
- Parties made out of trees (parties whose main element are trees).

On the other hand, "***Árboles de fiestas***" may have these meanings:

- Abbreviation of *Árboles que están de fiestas*: trees which are going or attending to a party.
- Trees used within parties (should be also expressed with: *Árboles para fiestas*).

As you can see, at least the meanings I can think of these phrases are very similar for both cases.

Comment: "Árboles de fiestas" is a phrase made up by me. I don't know exactly if it makes sense. I added the context where I found "Fiestas de árboles"

Answer (score 2):

The lyrics are written as poetry, a translation would be:

> Your eyes are like tree parties, they're my window.
>
> They're stars that guide my caravan.

Since poetry uses lots of figures of speech (metaphors, metonymy, synecdoche, etc), it's not always easy to make sense out of it.